# Uncaught TypeError: Object(...)(...).Class is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript

Can not figure out why I am getting TypeError when trying to implement this angular code.  It generates error around Class({constructor: function() {}}).  not sure why.  thanks for help

```
import "hello_angular/polyfills";

import { Component, NgModule    } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule          } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { FormsModule            } from "@angular/forms";
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";

var CustomerSearchComponent = Component({
  selector: "shine-customer-search",
  template: '\
<header> \
  <h1 class="h2">Customer Search</h1> \
</header> \
  '
}).Class({
  constructor: function() {
  }
});

var CustomerAppModule = NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ CustomerSearchComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ CustomerSearchComponent ]
})
.Class({
  constructor: function() {}
});
```

Comment: Which angular version are you using?

Comment: I have tried both ^5 and ^4

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20305

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your angular version in your `package.json` file to 4.1.3

```
{
"name": "shine",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "^4.1.3",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.1.3",
"@angular/core": "^4.1.3",
"@angular/forms": "^4.1.3",
"@angular/http": "^4.1.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^4.1.3",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.1.3",
"@rails/webpacker": "^3.2.0",
"bootstrap": "3",
"coffeescript": "1.12.7",
"core-js": "^2.5.3",
"rxjs": "^5.5.6",
"ts-loader": "^3.2.0",
"typescript": "^2.6.2",
"zone.js": "^0.8.20"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.7"
}
}
```